# Loop to Apply Multiple Symbology to Multiple Layers

Tags: arcpy, python, symbology, arcgis-10.5

I am trying to apply multiple symbology to multiply layers that I have created from multi-tasking custom tool. The tool applies buffer, clip tool to multiple feature classes and then all the feature classes are saved as feature layer.

I have also pre-defined .lyr files. This involves using  arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(in_layer,in_symbology_layer)

I would like to apply these pre-defined .lyr files to the feature layers that have been created. Pre-defined and created feature layers have the same name.

**Example:**

[image]

This code I have is as follows:

```
import os
import arcpy


filelist = os.listdir (r"C:\gdb\Created_Layers")

layerlist = os.listdir (r"C:\Tool\PreDefined_Layers")

for f in filelist:
    for s in layerlist:
       if f == s:
        arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(f,s)
```

But it doesn't work. I still see the random defined symbology for every feature layers that have been created.

Comment: Are you applying the symbology from within Arc? The layer list is reading the files from the path and not the files from the map, that might have something to do with it.

Comment: Yes, it needs to be like that. I'm trying to automate the method. The layers are saved within a folder that's why it's reading the files from the path. I do not know if it's the correct approach, Im not going to use the files from the map option if it's possible.

Comment: If I recall the ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management will apply a layer symbology to a layer that is within the map already. A lyr file just contains the symbology information for a feature. So applying outside an mxd will do nothing. You can however load the lyr file directly into a MXD and as long as it is pointing to the feature...you will have the symbology defined.

Comment: no, it does not need to be in the mxd. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/apply-symbology-from-layer.htm. Please check the code example bottom of the page. You can apply symbology outside an mxd to be precise .lyr file.

Comment: ok we may have got some wires mixed up there. Applying the lyr file (in Arc) will change the symbology. The lyr file is like a style guide telling Arc how you want something styled. If you load a feature / shapefile directly into ArcMap it wont style based on the lyr file until you apply it. However, if you open the lyr file and things are linked...as in the lyr file knows where the data sits, then you will see the predefined style / symbology. When you say it "doesnt work" what exactly doesnt it do and what do you do that makes you think it doesnt.